# How to make uneven text wrapping (not square or round) like this with semantic and clean HTML, CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

How to make text wrapping like this with semantic and clean HTML, CSS ? With compatible in all browser.

[image]

Adding different classes to `<p>` is the only solution I'm thinking if there is no other solution.

but with that way every time client would not be able to change classes, which is drawback.

Comment: Neat little tool you might like to see : http://www.csstextwrap.com/

Comment: It's doable, but it's not going to be clean nor semantic.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen - Agree with you

Comment: @Russell Dias- I know about this. If there is no other semantic way then i will use this as a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the image as a background on your `<p>` and then float transparent containers overtop of the background image in the shape that you don't want text to overlap.

```
<p>
    <span id="block1"></span>  
    <span id="block2"></span>  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ...
</p>
```

With the following CSS:

```
p {
   background: url(your-image.png) no-repeat 100% 0;
}

#block1 {
   float: right;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}

#block2 {
   clear: both;
   float: right;
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

The drawback though is that as with your paragraph class solution, this is a very manual fix. You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/mjMBz/1/).

Comment: +1 you solution is good but to keep blank `<span>` in code is not semantically correct

Comment: Well the problem here is that the "semantics" of an irregular image are just not expressible with HTML or CSS.  What does the shape of an image mean?  Well, maybe a lot of things, but in practical terms for page coding it's just a shape. HTML is not a page description language, as you know - it's intended to convey the meaning of content. There's just no provision for describing a single complex shape.