# Text flows around polygon edges in html

Tags: html, css

In my html content, I want to place an image at the bottom right corner of some container. While the image, like all images, is square in that it has a height and width, the actual visual image that the eye sees is not square. It could be a ball for example or a triangle. I also want text in this container but when the text is a lot, I would like it to flow around the edge of the visual image and not along the actual rectangle edges. Is this possible? Does html or css have some construct where you can setup the border (or edges) where text should stay away from?

Comment: Don't think this is possible with css

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594792/how-to-make-uneven-text-wrapping-not-square-or-round-like-this-with-semantic-a

Comment: You can try http://www.jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve the problem only with css and html you need to programming the page with many paragraphs (`<p>` tag) with various dimensions and set the image like a background image of the div wrapper.

```
#wrapper {
width:500px;
height:500px;
background-color: #fff; /*Default bg, similar to the background's base color*/
background-image: url("image.png");
background-position: right bottom; /*Positioning*/
background-repeat: no-repeat; /*Prevent showing multiple background images*/
}
```

After that set any paragraphs with custom width to set the text around the image.
Unfortunately i don't know any other "automatic" solutions.

Maybe, you can find a valid plugin here:

[check this another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491691/flow-text-around-a-transparent-png-with-css-jquery-anything)